# Rails Devise Token Auth Reset Password Flow - How to deep link from 302 redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, deep-linking, devise-token-auth

I am trying to implement a reset password flow with devise token auth gem: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

The end client will be a mobile device (e.g. iOS, Android). I am uncertain as to how the native clients will be able to catch the url to reset password and display a password form through deep linking. Here are the general steps as I understand them:

1. Fire a POST to `auth/password` with an email and `redirect_url`
2. This will send an email with a link to reset the password and an included `reset_password_token` query param.
3. Clicking on the link fires a GET to `auth/password/edit`
4. This GET then fires a http 302 redirect to the `redirect_url` sent in the first request with the `reset_password_token` in the query params. The `redirect_url` should route to the form intended to display a password field to reset a user's password. On mobile clients, ideally this would be handled as a deep link.

I am confused as to how the mobile apps will handle step 4. I heard it's difficult to deep link in a native app through a 302 redirect/may not be possible. Is there a part of the flow I am misunderstanding perhaps? I'd appreciate any clarity on how I can implement this flow successfully for mobile clients.

For reference here is the guide I am following from the official docs: https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/usage/reset_password